# Can't Build Android Emulator in VS Code

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

I am trying to create an Android emulator in vs Code, it was working just fine before I deleted it because I had had some problems with it, thinking it would be a good idea to delete it and just create a new one.
I am getting the following message `Error: AVD not created.` 
I ran flutter doctor and I got this

```
[√] Android toolchain - develop for     
    Android devices (Android SDK version    29.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[√] VS Code (version 1.45.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available



! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: does emulator -list-avds show any avd?  https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline

Comment: I tried flutter emulators and I got this :1 available emulator:

Nexus_6_API_28 • Nexus 6 API 28 • Google • android..but the thing is this emulator is so heavy and takes for ever to launch , and make the performance very bad

Comment: i think you should create your emulator through the Android Studio. VSCode will recognize it after you set it up on android studio